# Custom rules or script for Https recording in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have been using the HTTP(s) recording controller in Jmeter for some time particularly for performance testing. Now I am exploring something really cool. I don't know if its feasible and need your suggestions/inputs on it.

Here is what I plan to do:

Android/IOS App hybrid

Recording custom requests only from Jmeter ( my App makes tons of request to fetch data from different sources). I am looking to record only request which start with "Ads.abc.abc" ( this request has 100 custom parameters that are build within the App) and then for the captured request, have assertion on these custom parameters( yes, on the request that was captured and not the response)and then have some custom script which will basically assert how many "ads.abc.abc" requests were captured.

For a full blown framework, I need Jmeter to launch programatically--> then set up the HTTP recording controller and start recording all the calls from my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter out "unwanted" domains via "URL Patterns to Exclude" input of the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder.

Example regular expression to exclude Google and Facebook traffic will look like:

```
^((?!google|facebook).)*$
```

In regards to starting JMeter's proxy programmatically, there is no obvious way of doing that, however you can consider switching to [Mobile Recorder](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1946705-mobile-recorder) solution

Comment: thanks dimitri, is there a way I can do assertion on the recorded request, if it contains some specific parameter or not ( I am not looking to assert the response just the request). And then to scan the whole recording controller and basically count the number of requests that were made .

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this programmatically Record in Jmeter--> On the recorded Requests Run assertions based on some custom rules --> I have these 100s of third party requests that are made and I need to validate them everytime the build goes out.. I have been able to acheive this with my selenium Appium code but it just kind of becomes unmanageable when ever I have to do it for every release

Comment: something like where I keep my assertions static and they basically run on every new HTTP(s) recordin I do ,, some sort of global assertion?